# I get 404 error - asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

My task is to create services (using asp.net api) and use it for android aplication.

I have never done anything like this so I have a problems at begining. :(

First I created Class Library with few classes.
Second I created asp.net web application and refered class library into it.

My first problem is that I dont know how to access to methode from controller. So, I tried to just start without it, to see does it even work... When I runned it I added controller to the path but I get error.

I runner it like this: `http://localhost:51041/ValuesController1`

**Error is this:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could >have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the >following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /ValuesController1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Ok, now my code:

**Controller class:**

```
    public class ValuesController1 : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    public List<BuzzMonitor.Web.Message> Search()
    {
        //return new BuzzMonitor.Web.MessageHandler.Search(...);
    }
}
```

**MessageHandler class:**

```
public class MessageHandler
{
    private List<Message> _dummyMessages = new List<Message>()
        {
            new Message(){
                MessageId = 1,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
                Text = "Srpska vodoprivreda...",
                Autor = "Marko Markovic",
                Source = "Twitter"

            },
            new Message(){
                MessageId = 2,
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 27),
                Text = "Aerodrom Beograd...",
                Autor = "Zoran Zoric",
                Source = "B92"

            }
        };

    public List<Message> GetLatestMessages(int nrMessagesToReturn)
    {
        List<Message> retVal;

        retVal = this._dummyMessages.GetRange(0, nrMessagesToReturn);

        return retVal;
    }

    public List<Message> Search(string text, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<int> themeIds, List<int> sourceIds, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        List<Message> retVal;

        retVal = this.Search(text, dateFrom, dateTo, themeIds, sourceIds);

        if (retVal != null && retVal.Count > 0)
        {
            retVal = retVal.GetRange(pageIndex * pageSize, pageSize);
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public List<Message> Search(string text, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, List<int> themeIds, List<int> sourceIds)
    {
        List<Message> retVal = null;

        retVal = this._dummyMessages.Where(m => m.Text.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 &&
            m.CreatedDate >= dateFrom &&
            m.CreatedDate < dateTo &&
            (themeIds == null || themeIds.Count == 0 || (themeIds.Contains(m.ThemeId))) &&
            (sourceIds == null || sourceIds.Count == 0 || (sourceIds.Contains(m.SourceId)))).ToList<Message>();

        return retVal;
    }


}
```

**Message class:**

```
    public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Autor { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

    public int ThemeId { get; set; }

    public int SourceId { get; set; }
}
```

So, problems are:
 1. I dont know how to call Search in controler from MessageHandler.
 2. I get error message and I dont know is it because I dont have everythig I need in controller or I need to set some configurations...

I am using VS 2010.

Thank you for helping and sorry if my questions seems stupid...

Comment: What happens if you try `http://localhost:51041/api/ValuesController1/Get`

Comment: You should read how the [routing works in Web Api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) it's heavily conventions based and the name of your controller and actions must follow the conventions for it to work.

Comment: @RobH Thank you for advice, now I am reading but I dont have App_Start and AppConfig.cs in it. Maybe because of version or something... Or do I need to create it manualy maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename your controller class to XXXController. For example, in this case call it ValuesController. The default routing in WebAPI is set up with this code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                          //The name of this route.
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",   //The url, note the prefix "api" is hard-coded.
    new {                               //The default values:
        controller = "Home",            //{controller} in URL defaults to Home (i.e. HomeController)
        action = "Index",               //{action} in URL defaults to Index method
        id = UrlParameter.Optional });  //The id part is optional
```

An example URL based on the above route is `/api/Home/action/id`. Note that the `Controller` suffix of the class is not used. So to map this to your renamed ValuesController it becomes:

```
http://localhost:51041/api/Values/Get
```

Comment: I did this but I still have problems, i think that I need to configurate it somehow, but I dont know what to do. I am using VS 2010, and in project I dont have App_Start and WebAPiConfig in it :/

Comment: What is in your `Application_Start` method in the `Global.asax.cs` file?

Comment: That's odd, sounds like you have a partial template. Try adding in the default route in `Application_Start` like this: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });`

Comment: I added this. I just saw you edited your post, I dont know where I need to add routhes.MapRoute(...). Sorry for so many stupid questions, but I'm kinda lost laa... :/

Comment: with just this code: `Application_Start like this: GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });` I don't have error 404 anymore!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54619/discussion-between-malaaiko-and-davidg).

Answer (score 3):

I think you may need to change `ValuesController1` to `ValuesController`

and use

```
http://localhost:51041/api/Values
```

Comment: still same :/ this didn't help.

Comment: @MalaAiko, how you configured routing?

Comment: I didn't do anything particular :( I will read about it now and try! I never did this before so it's confusing for me :(